# scan root directory using scandir

Tags: unix, lua

I am trying to use `scandir` function to scan the root directory using Lua. If I use the below code for any other directory it works well. It scans the directory and returns all the files present.

```
directory="//home//"
function scandir(directory)
    local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen
    for filename in popen('ls -a "'..directory..'"'):lines() do
        i = i + 1
        t[i] = filename--loop populates the array with the scanned files
    end
    print(unpack(t))
    return t--t contains all the scanned files 
end

scandir(directory)
```

I have few files under

```
user@user:~/.program$ ls 
file1 file2
```

how do I set my path in directory such that it scans the root dir to access `file1` and `file2`??

Comment: Watch out for some special characters in filenames. e.g. a filename can contain a newline; which will result in `:lines()` incorrectly splitting.

Answer (score 3):

You don't escape forward slash `/` in strings. To scan for `/home`, use:

```
directory = "/home"
```

The root directly is represented with a single slash:

```
directory = "/"
```